# Configuring Eclipse with MinGW

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

My computer runs under Windows 7 32-bit. I have:

- Installed MinGW using the installer (mingw32-base, mingw32-gcc-g++ and msys-base) to C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
- Edited the Path to MinGW and MSYSM by opening **System Properties->Enviroment Variables->Path** and adding: **C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;** to the list.
- Installed eclipse for C/C++ Developers.

I've Tried:

- setting the Configuration to "Build" in Eclipse under **Project->Properties->C/C++ Build**. (But when I compile a test application, it resets to Debug, also If I click 'apply' afterwards.)
- compiling both a C and a C++ Project.

I get the Following error message in the eclipse console:

```
    **** Rebuild of configuration Release for project Cpp test Project ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\Cpp test Project.o ..\src\Cpp test Project.cpp
g++ -oCpptestProject.exe src\Cpp test Project.o
Warning: .drectve `-aligncomm:"___hexdig_D2A",5' unrecognized
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/crt2.o(.text+0x1f1)C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 information.
:crt1.c: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o)(.text+0x5e3)C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: Dwarf Error: found dwarf version '4', this reader only handles version 2 information.
:glob.c: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o)(.text+0x690):glob.c: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o)(.text+0x7e9):glob.c: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o)(.text+0x82d):glob.c: undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a(glob.o)(.text+0xc0d):glob.c: more undefined references to `__chkstk_ms' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 3057  ms.
```

I've been skimming the internet for an hour or so, read the MinGW installationguide a million times and followed some University installation guide for installing C++ eclipse. ALL TO NO AVAIL! Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:c#]??

Comment: Do you have more than one MinGW (or Cygwin) installation on your machine? Do you have any libraries linked? Can you please try a very simple program (eg. a main with a printf) or post your code?

Comment: Btw. your project paths has some blanks, please test again using a path **without** any blank. Sometimes this can cause some problems.